# Elasticsearch query must not match text from field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get the results that do not match "statusCode": 200

In order to match text from field you use

```
GET index01/_search?pretty
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
GET ucs_heartbeat/_search?pretty
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "statusCode":{
        "query": 200,
        "operator": "must_not"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: note that there is no _operator_ called `must_not` for `match query`. Only available operators are `and`(default) and `or`. Consider using `term` query over `match` query for all structured fields like `keyword, numbers`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this instead

```
GET ucs_heartbeat/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "statusCode": 200
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to perform this kind of search by using a regexp search(for a String -text and keyword- type field),  something like-  "bool":{"must":[{"regexp": {"statusCode.keyword": {"value": "~(200)","flags": "ALL"}}}]} , and also, is there any difference in performance, if this query works ?

Comment: @soumitragoswami regexp queries are notably slower. If you know in advance what and how you're going to query you can prepare your data at indexing time so that regexp queries are not necessary anymore. Your mileage may vary, so you should definitely try it out and then if you hit performance issues, look for other possible indexing solutions. Feel free to create a new question with your specific issue, though

Comment: Hi, I created a question on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410594/using-regexp-search-inside-a-must-bool-query-vs-using-must-not-bool-query

Answer (score 0):

A possible string query could be:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "NOT statusCode: 200"
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": []
}
```