# Using Regexp Search inside a must bool query vs using must_not bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make queries like - get all documents containing/not containing "some value" for a given field
-get all documents having value equal/not equal to "some value" for a given field.

As per my mapping the fields are String type meaning they support both keyword and full text search something like:

```
"myField" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
```

I was initially using regex matching like(this query is for not matches)  :

```
"bool": {
  "must":[
    {
     "regexp": {
               "myField.keyword": {
                 "value": "~(some value)",
                 "flags": "ALL"
                }
           }
      }
    ]
}
```

so, basically `~(word)` for not, `.*word.*` for contains and `~(.*word.*)` for not containing.

But, then also came across the 'must_not' bool query, so I understand I can also add a 'must_not' for the not equals cases clause along with the 'must' and 'should' clauses(for boolean AND and OR between other fields) in my bigger bool query, but still not sure about contains and not contains search, can someone definitively explain, what is the best practice here speaking both in terms of performance and accuracy of the result set returned.

ElasticSearch version used - Currently transitioning from v 6.3 to v 7.1.1

Comment: May you please show a couple of examples of your documents and queries? For instance, do you need to match entire words (separated with spaces or punctuation in text), or parts of words?