# ElasticSearch Filter not working with must AND must_not

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, querydsl

I am trying to filter out errors in Kibana, but not all errors, just errors that do not have a specific string in the message field. My query is as follows:

```
GET search-apps/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-120m",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "level": "error"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "message": "Exception thrown while fetching records from Kinesis"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that the filter ignores the "must_not" as I still get errors that have that string in the message field. Is there some sort of order of execution where it is ignoring the must_not? The must works fine, I only get level:error returned, but I also get results that have that string in the message.
This also works if I wanted to only return results with the message field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "Exception thrown while fetching records from Kinesis",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, [per this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252614/elasticsearch-query-must-not-match-text-from-field) the opposite doesn't work as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question already contains the solution to your "problem".

In your `must_not`-clause you are using a `term`-query which tests for exact match, whereas in your "test"-query you use a `phrase`-query. If your message contains the *phrase*, but also some additional bytes/text, the `term`-query no longer matches.

**Solution**
Simply replace `term` by `match_phrase` in your `bool`-query.